# Distributive Propery with Fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I have several problems in this format and I don't know where to start.  I understand the distributive property until I get to some fractions.  The directions say write each fraction as a sum or difference.  Here is an example of one of them:

$$\displaystyle\frac{2m-5}{9}$$

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by $\underline{2m-5}$? (If that's what you actually want.)

Comment: Hint: Consider  $\frac {1}{9}=9^{-1} $

Answer (score 4):

Another way to write
$$\frac{2m-5}{9}$$
is
$$\frac{1}{9}(2m-5)$$
From this it is much easier to see how the distributive property applies. We get
$$\frac{1}{9}(2m)-\frac{1}{9}(5)=\frac{2m}{9}-\frac{5}{9}$$

Answer (score 2):

$${2m-5\over 9} = \frac19(2m-5)=\frac{2m}9-\frac59$$

You have distributed the fraction $$\frac19$$ in order to write the original expression as a difference.

Comment: Alright thanks, I reformatted it

Comment: You're welcome.